# Remove Signature from Xml

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a file like this <ufile.io/g8dy86x0>
I'd like remove signature.
I try this code but doesn't work

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
doc.Load(_filename)
Dim rnode As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Signature")
doc.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(rnode)
```

What should i try ?

Comment: That's neither a valid filename, nor is it valid XML - it's missing a closing tag. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Excuse me. Here the new file  [link](https://ufile.io/2netq2h6)